# Force chromium and firefox to use TLS 1.2

Tags: firefox, chromium

How can you force Chromium and Firefox to use [TLS 1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.2) instead of the previously less secure versions?

Using Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Please, either firefox or chromium, not both.

Comment: Why? Sort of silly having two questions, one for each browser, and some muppet would mark those as a duplicates. And, the question is clear what it is asking about.

Comment: @wilf is one issue per question. Not 2, 3, 4, 5. One. Also, people might know how to do this is chromium but not in firefox, the same backwards.

Comment: Asking a different question just for Chromium may make some people happy... It is clear what the question is, those flagging close votes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Force Firefox to use your desired TLS version:

- Write in address bar: `about:config`
- Confirm to proceed

Default settings are:

```
security.tls.version.min = 0
security.tls.version.max = 1
```

- 1 = TLS 1.0
- 2 = TLS 1.1
- 3 = TLS 1.2

Set the values you need.

Comment: More info can  be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967266) & [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*)

Comment: This doesn't answers Chromium.

Comment: @Braiam - Yes, that may prompt the OP to ask a different question for Chromium - nearly exactly what you wanted.